# Is mutating two distinct part of an object in an unsynchronized way unsafe?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Lets say I have a relatively simple object with two properties :

```java
@Data
public class MyObject {
    public Integer a;
    public Integer b;
}
```

can I safely mutate a in some thread and b in some other thread safely ? for example, would this code be safe from race conditions ?

```java
public MyObject compute() {
    MyObject newObj = new MyObject();
    List<Runnable> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    Runnable computeATask = () -> {
        Integer a = computeA();
        newObj.setA(a);
    };
    Runnable computeBTask = () -> {
        Integer b = computeB();
        newObj.setB(b);
    };
    tasks.add(computeATask);
    tasks.add(computeBTask);
    tasks.stream().parallel().forEach(Runnable::run);
    return newObj;
}
```

Comment: @Kayaman depends on the context. In the example, a parallel stream is used, which makes the decision to use multiple threads (or not) and guarantees correct visibility of the results when `forEach` returned. And there’s no other access to these variable prior to the completion.

Comment: @Holger ah I shouldn't have spoken so hastily. So *visibility* is guaranteed by the parallel `forEach()` *after* the operation, but e.g. [updating a thread-unsafe collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36033134/2541560) isn't safe due to the concurrent operation. I very much appreciate your continuing insight on concurrency and other issues on SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is specified in [JLS, §17.6. Word Tearing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.6):

> One consideration for implementations of the Java Virtual Machine is that every field and array element is considered distinct; updates to one field or element must not interact with reads or updates of any other field or element.

So the fact that `a` might written by a different thread than `b` in your example, does not create any data race.

But it still requires a thread safe mechanism to read the result. In your example, it’s the parallel stream which guarantees that the initiating thread can safely read the two variables after `forEach` returned.

You example can be simplified to

```java
public MyObject compute() {
    MyObject newObj = new MyObject();
    Stream.<Runnable>of(() -> newObj.setA(computeA()), () -> newObj.setB(computeB()))
        .parallel().forEach(Runnable::run);
    return newObj;
}
```

But the recommended pattern would be to execute the calculation first, followed by constructing the object, which can be designed as immutable object then.

```java
public class MyObject {
  public final Integer a, b;

  public MyObject(Integer a, Integer b) {
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
  }
}
```

```java
public MyObject compute() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> computeA())
      .thenCombine(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> computeB()), MyObject::new)
      .join();
}
```

This way, you can be sure that any thread seeing the `MyObject` will see consistent values for the fields, regardless of what happens in the remaining application.